# Is there a better way to get an older value after an EntityState.Modified in EF5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I just want to know if it existe a better way to get the value in database after an EntityState.Modified. My syntaxe :

```
db.Entry(UserProfile).State = EntityState.Modified;
var olderPhoto = (string)db.Entry(UserProfile).GetDatabaseValues()["Photo"];
```

Thank you for an eventually answer

Answer (score 1):

Well, depends. If you have no control over when the entity is being modified and you want to be able to get the old value *after* it's been modified (but presumably before it's been committed), then that's pretty much your only resort: fetch it fresh from the database.

However, if you can simply store the original somewhere before you modify it, then you can just use that without having to requery the database. The catch here is that you must explicitly store any and all values you need into a variable(s), just storing the entity itself would only store the pointer to the same instance.

```
var olderPhoto = UserProfile.Photo;

UserProfile.Photo = newPhoto;
db.Entry(UserProfile).State = EntityState.Modified;

// use olderPhoto
```

Comment: Ok, thank you but I have an entiy (exist in database) that provide from the view that I handle after, without the photo string filled but I have a value in database. Can you send me the difference between originalValue and currentValue ?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is...:

```
db.Entry(UserProfile).State = EntityState.Modified;
var olderPhoto = db.Users.Find(UserProfile.UserID).Photo.ToString();
```